# Can we merge the ip and ip-address tags?

Tags: discussion, retag-request, tag-merge

Can we merge the ip and ip-address tags?

- [ip-address](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/ip-address) (288 questions)
- [ip](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/ip) (47 questions)

Comment: Which way do you suggest?

Comment: @Seth merge [ip] into [ip-address], retag all [ip] tags and possibly make [ip] a synonym of [ip-address]?

Comment: Definitely. [ip-address] is a better tag to keep around because there's much less ambiguity IMO.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure where the ip address tag should be used. I know what it means, but I feel that all the possible topics are well addressed with the [networking](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/networking) and related tags. There have been questions about [using ip addresses range with iptables](https://askubuntu.com/q/637453/169736), something that doesn't have to do with the underlaying internet protocol but just with the functionality of iptables, or with [network cammeras](https://askubuntu.com/q/491452/169736) which the OP uses the misnomer of "ip cameras", I've never used that term. So, I prefer not to merge but retag these questions as a cursory glance tells me that [there are some problems with just merging](https://askubuntu.com/posts/243438/revisions) these tags.

Comment: IP Cameras are actually what networked cameras are called, at least in my part of the world.  Not that that has anything to do with this tag, though.

Comment: @Seth exactly my point, what has to do cameras with the internet protocol?

Comment: Definitely.  I'm not opposed to removing the tag (at the moment) but merging is still the first step.  I'll do this after dinner.

Comment: @Seth dunno you, but [I've always seen that the clean up is done *before* merging](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/269701/792066). Is easier to spot outliers when the posts are less. A light check of mine revealed at least 3 questions that doesn't make sense.

Comment: go ahead and do some cleaning if you want (just watch what you do with other tags). We can't burniate it on our own though. I will take a quick look through later as well.